# Solve cannot return NOT[A==B] in equations results

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

can you help me to return NOT[A==B] for Solve operation. in below code it does not return zP!=14

```
 Simplify[Solve[
       Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP}, Element[{x, y, z, xP}, Integers], 
        false == false && xPP == x && yPP == y && 
         zPP == z && ((zPP == 13 && xP == xPP && yP == 67 && 
             zP == zPP) || (Not [zPP == 14] && xP == xPP && yP == 24))]], 
      Element[{x, y, z, xP}, Integers]] /.  ConditionalExpression :> And
```

Answer:
{{xP -> x, yP -> 24}, {xP -> x, yP -> 67, z -> 13, zP -> 13}}

**What I Expect**:
{{xP -> x && z!=14, yP -> 24 && z!=14}, {xP -> x, yP -> 67, z -> 13, zP -> 13}}

Now if I use Reduce instead of Solve it will show me, but for some reasons i MUST use solve, if it is possible.
***Reduce***:
**x == xP && ((yP == 67 && z == 13 && zP == 13) || (yP == 24 &&
z != 14))**

Comment: Can  you  apply Solve to the output of Reduce?

Comment: Why do you need `Solve`? The requirement to use only Solve feels like [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) ... Do you know `ToRules`?

Comment: @Szabolcs the reason I need Solve is ; solve returns me x -> a. based on my equations, I need every xP ->.... in a structured way. but reduce returns in various format each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of the `MaxExtraConditions -> All]` option, one obtains

```
Simplify[Solve[Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP}, Element[{x, y, z, xP}, Integers], 
false == false && xPP == x && yPP == y && 
zPP == z && ((zPP == 13 && xP == xPP && yP == 67 && 
zP == zPP) || (Not[zPP == 14] && xP == xPP && yP == 24))], 
Element[{x, y, z, xP}, Integers], MaxExtraConditions -> All]] /.  
 ConditionalExpression :> And
```

> `{{xP -> x && (x | y | z) \[Element] Integers && z != 14 &&  yP == 24}, {z ->  13 && (x | y) \[Element] Integers && yP == 67 && zP == 13,  xP -> x && (x | y) \[Element] Integers && yP == 67 && zP == 13}}`

and a warning "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables."

The command

```
Simplify[Resolve[Exists[{xPP,yPP,zPP},Element[{x,y,z,xP},Integers],false==false&&xPP==x&&yPP==y&&zPP==z&&((zPP==13&&xP==xPP&&yP==67&&zP==zPP)||(Not[zPP==14]&&xP==xPP&&yP==24))],Element[{x,y,z,xP},Integers]]]/.  ConditionalExpression:>And
```

produces

> `(xP | z | y | x) \[Element] Integers &&  x == xP && ((yP == 24 && z != 14) || (yP == 67 && z == 13 &&  zP == 13))`

without any warning.